# Factorial task is incorrectly outputting zero

Tags: c#, factorial

I'm having a problem in the dry run of a program. I'm not getting why my program is giving 0 in the output. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Task_8_Set_III
{
    class Program                      
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 3;
            int c = i / fact(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static int fact(int value)
        {
            if (value ==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return (value * (fact(value - 1)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is wrong: the factorial is fact(i), not i/fact(i).

Comment: @Dathan: The code may not be wrong, it may just be incorrect in its labeling. The assignment very well could direct the user to divide the number by its factorial.

Comment: It is safer to write if (value  <= 1), just in case

Comment: Please do not forget that 0! (i.e. fact(0)) equals zero by definition. Now your fact() method throws OverflowException if run with 0 as a parameter.

Comment: @Yuiry: Why did you make this question community wiki? This is a standard, closed-ended question.

Comment: Didn't mean to set it to community. Did setting it to homework make it that way? Feel free to roll back if thats what did it.

Comment: @Igor: 0! is one, not zero. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0!

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Yes, you're absolutely right, it was a typo, sorry for that.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, you're right, and you correctly expressed what I meant, though what I wrote clearly says something different.  (c:  Rather than "the code is wrong," should be "the result is mislabeled."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing integer variables. You're dividing 3 by 6, which gets rounded down to the next integer, which is zero.

Use the type 'double' instead of 'int' to get the value you're probably looking for.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when a more complete (and higher-voted) answer was given three minutes prior?

Answer (score 8):

It's because you're doing integer division - the result of dividing one int by another is an int - since `i / Factorial(i)` is less than 1 (for i > 2), the result gets truncated to 0. You can fix this by converting the numerator and divisor to doubles:

```
double c = (double)i / (double)fact(i);
```

EDIT: for i = 1, you have 1/1 which is 1 for integer division and no truncation occurs. The same thing happens for i = 2: (2/Fact(2)) 2/2 = 1.

Comment: but when i initialize i=1; it gives 1.. why is this so then?

Comment: @Abid: because 1/fact(1) is 1/1 is 1.

Comment: @Abid: Look at Danthan's comment to your question. 1 factorial is 1, but 3 factorial is 6. Since you're dividing the original number by its factorial, you get 3/6. While that arithmetically is .5, the fractional portion gets truncated in integer division, leaving you with 0.

Answer (score 2):

As Lee said, you're doing integer division in line

`int c = i / fact(i);`

Change c & i to decimal or double...

`double c = (double)i / fact(i);`